# How to run the service never end until app is uninstall?

Tags: android, performance, google-maps, android-fragments

I have background mode on for location services and aiming to send out location (latitude and longitude) to the server every 30 minutes in android but i am get the location update until application is active state.i.e,clear the recent app service also stop.

How to achieve this scenario.can u post me some sample code?.

Comment: Which android version you are using?

Comment: minimum sdk version 19 maximum version 26

Comment: On testing device?

Comment: redmi4aA os version marshmallow 6.01

Comment: Please paste your code for better understanding.

Comment: this post my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757617/how-to-create-forground-service-never-stop-when-application-is-inactive

Comment: you should implement like this https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/background-location-updates-android-o/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#5

Answer (score 0):

in your case you can register alarmManager which runs every 30min and check's the user gps if gps was available than fetches location data and sends it to server ! use JobScheduler for api 21 and above

and if you want to have never ended service in android read this article  :

https://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android